# how can i access get father name and store it to

Tags: swift

```
class parent{
var fathername:String="sugumar"
}


 class child:parent{
 var car:String }
```

how can I get  father name from the base class and store it to the property child in derived class child

Comment: It's already there! Did you try accessing it by creating an instance of child?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have created an instance of the child class. Accessing the fathername variable of the parent class is just as same as accessing the car variable of the child class.

```
let childInstance = child()
print(childInstance.fathername)
print(childInstance.car)
```

You might wanna give a value to the car variable before creating the instance.